# Windows Phone 7 Development - Image Source Issue

Tags: windows-phone-7

While developing a project for Windows Phone 7, I'm adding an image control onto the Grid and using the following code in C# to set the image source:-

```
 Uri nUri = new Uri("/TestImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
            BitmapImage nBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(nUri);
            FacebookImage.Source = nBitmapImage;
```

The problem is that whenever I use custom images, they do not show up when I build and run the app on the emulator. Whereas, if I change the image file name in the above code to one of the images that are included in the project by default (ApplicationIcon.png), the image shows up upon running. I would like to know if this is a problem with the code or with the custom image files I'm using. I'm ensuring that the images I'm creating are proper and have the same attributes as the images included by default.
Could someone please help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click on your custom picture in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. Then, look at the property window (press F4 if it's closed), and at the "Build Action" line. It basically tells the compiler how to embed your file in the application. The build action of ApplicationIcon.png should be "Content", just set the same one for your custom pictures.